# How to colorize a cell depending on it's value compared to the value of the cell next to it in Excel?

Tags: excel

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
   | A | B | C 
 --------------
 1 | 3 | 6 | 5 
 2 | 5 | 5 | 7
 3 | 2 | 3 | 3
```

I want to:

1. Compare the values of the cells with the values of the cells above them
2. Color the background of the cell depending on this comparison

So:

- If I compare the value of A2 to A1, 5 > 3, A2 should have a background of red
- If I compare the value of A3 to A2, 2 < 5, A3 should have a background of green
- If I compare the value of B2 to B1, 5 < 6, B2 should have a background of green
- If I compare the value of B3 to B2, 3 < 5, B3 should have a background of green
- If I compare the value of C2 to C1, 7 > 5, C2 should have a background of red
- If I compare the value of C3 to C2, 3 < 7, C3 should have a background of green

Any ideas on how to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Meibrah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To color the cells, select the range A2:C3 and choose from the home tab of the ribbon:

*Conditional Formatting|Highlight Cell Rules|Greater Than...*

with the settings shown, then repeat for *Less Than...* with Green Text.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from Lori, I would like to add one more thing.

Instead of using 2 conditional format rules (red + green), just set the background color to your default (e.g. green) and use 1 conditional format rule to turn the cell red.